# How do I search a vector for a region of elements?

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of strings, and altogether the strings are basically a text document in a format similar to markdown.

There are sections in the document that look something like this:

```
===FooHeader===

stuff...
more stuff...

----
```

The end of the section is indicated with 4 dashes.

So in this vector that I have, there may be many sections.

I want to extract one particular section from the document.

What would be the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Based on the name of the section, which is simply a string.

Comment: I'm unable to think of which functions I would use for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it could look something like this:

```
(defn find-region [start? end? data] 
  (take-while (complement end?) 
              (drop-while (complement start?) data)))

user=> (find-region #{1} #{-1} [10 20 30 1 30 4 2 3 4 -1 1])
;;=> (1 30 4 2 3 4)
```

or in your case:

```
(find-region #{"===FooHeader==="} #{"----"} lines)
```

Comment: Beautiful. I like it.

Comment: I'm also wondering why you used sets in your answer, I'm new to Clojure so I'm curious what the reasoning is.

Comment: @BlaineLafreniere Sets can be used as functions to essentially test for equality easier. `#{1}` is basically the same as the function `(fn [x] (= x 1))`, and it gets nicer as you add more elements to the set to test for more things. Note what `(#{1} 1)` and `(#{1} 2)` evaluate to.